# RF line: routing it orthogonal over SPI digital signal lines

Tags: rf, interference, pcb-antenna, crosstalk

SPI will be kept below 1MHz. RF signal is under 434 MHz. Is this crossing fine through the big zero ohm resistor ?
Side question: will the outermost SPI line (it is the chip select one), or any of the SPI lines, interfere with the trace antenna that I shall be adding soon down below ?

[image]

Comment: It does not look ok. Can you spin around the IC?

Comment: Agree with @jay, spin the IC 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: Ok, and that will help how ?

Comment: When the chip is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, you can route the SPI directly to the chip on the left side, then keep your RF feed path on the right with minimal overlap.